# Join elements in a Stream using new line separator

Tags: java, join, java-stream, apache-commons

I have the next list of elements in a Set and I'm trying to print these messages with a new line separator, but it seems that it's not possible to do in this way. I've tried using "/n" as well but I'm getting just the character printed in the screen, something like:

"The field xxxxxis not a valid xxxxx Value `\r\n`The field xxxx is not a valid xxx Value "

```
Set<String> messages;

 public String printValidationMessages() {
    if (this.messages != null && !this.messages.isEmpty()) {
      return this.messages.stream()
          .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
          .collect(Collectors.joining(System.getProperty("line.separator")));
    }
    return BLANK_SPACE;
 }
```

There is a way to achieve that line separation between each element using streams?

Thanks!

Comment: cannot replicate on my machine.

Comment: How are you printing the String?

Comment: Which console are you using? `Collectors.joining("\n")` always works for me. Or else try `joining("\r\n")`.

Comment: In a rest answer it must work? for me is not working. Just prints the \n character.

Comment: So you are sending the strings with a framework that intentionally escapes line breaks in the output. That’s how it is *supposed* to work. Having actual line breaks in the middle of a string would make the output invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working fine on my console. Can you please check where are your printing?

```
static Set<String> messages = new HashSet<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        messages.add("The field xxxxxis not a valid xxxxx Value");
        messages.add("The field xxxxxis");

        System.out.print(printValidationMessages());

    }
    static Predicate<String> p = s->!s.isEmpty();
    public static String printValidationMessages() {
        if (messages != null && !messages.isEmpty()) {
            return messages.stream().filter(p)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(System.getProperty("line.separator")));
        }
        return "";
    }
```